# foreach loop iterating only once? C# Unity3D

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to Instantiate a tree prefab based on transforms (specifically the position and rotation) that are loaded from a firebase database.

The problem here is that the foreach loop only iterates one time even though there are a total of 4 children in snapshot.Children, so I am confused as to why it only runs once.

This is the method

```
public void GetTrees()
   {
       reference.Child("Player").Child(scenarioName).GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
       {
           if (task.IsFaulted)
           {
               Debug.LogError("Error");
           }
           else if (task.IsCompleted)
           {
               DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;

               foreach (DataSnapshot tree in snapshot.Children)
               {
                   xPos = float.Parse(tree.Child("xPos").Value.ToString());
                   yPos = float.Parse(tree.Child("yPos").Value.ToString());
                   zPos = float.Parse(tree.Child("zPos").Value.ToString());

                   xRot = float.Parse(tree.Child("xRot").Value.ToString());
                   yRot = float.Parse(tree.Child("yRot").Value.ToString());
                   zRot = float.Parse(tree.Child("zRot").Value.ToString());
                   wRot = float.Parse(tree.Child("wRot").Value.ToString());

                   Vector3 loadTreePosition = new Vector3(xPos, yPos, zPos);
                   Quaternion loadTreeRotation = new Quaternion(xRot, yRot, zRot, wRot);

                   //returns the position of Tree 0 (31.63, .03, -38.79)
                   Debug.Log("Tree Positons " + loadTreePosition); 

                   //returns the rotation of Tree 0 (0,0,0,1)
                   Debug.Log("Tree Rotations " + loadTreeRotation);

                   //returns 4
                   Debug.Log(snapshot.ChildrenCount);

                   Instantiate(treePrefab, loadTreePosition, loadTreeRotation);

                   //THIS DOES NOT RETURN ANYTHING 
                   Debug.Log(snapshot.ChildrenCount);
               }
           }
       });
   }
```

Here is the console with the debug.log statements shown in the method
[debug log console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKrjA.png)

Here is the database information as json

```
{
  "Player" : {
    "test" : {
      "Tree 0" : {
        "mesh" : "palm-01 Instance",
        "wRot" : 1,
        "xPos" : 31.629507064819336,
        "xRot" : 0,
        "yPos" : 0.029083967208862305,
        "yRot" : 0,
        "zPos" : -38.7875862121582,
        "zRot" : 0
      },
      "Tree 1" : {
        "mesh" : "palm-01 Instance",
        "wRot" : 1,
        "xPos" : 31.059694290161133,
        "xRot" : 0,
        "yPos" : 0.029083967208862305,
        "yRot" : 0,
        "zPos" : -40.921390533447266,
        "zRot" : 0
      },
      "Tree 2" : {
        "mesh" : "palm-01 Instance",
        "wRot" : 1,
        "xPos" : 31.059694290161133,
        "xRot" : 0,
        "yPos" : 0.029083967208862305,
        "yRot" : 0,
        "zPos" : -40.921390533447266,
        "zRot" : 0
      },
      "Tree 3" : {
        "mesh" : "palm-01 Instance",
        "wRot" : 1,
        "xPos" : 31.46793556213379,
        "xRot" : 0,
        "yPos" : 0.029083967208862305,
        "yRot" : 0,
        "zPos" : -43.42497253417969,
        "zRot" : 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are sure there are 4 children (as in, you have debugged that)? If so, do you happen to get any errors in the console that might indicate it's not able to complete the routine?

Comment: @Bart 
I did Debug.Log the snapshot.ChildrenCount and it returned 4 in the console.
And there are no errors in the console either. I think the problem might be with calling Instantiate because when I remove that it does iterate all 4 times, but when I place it back it iterates only once.

Comment: Write a Log Message with snapshot.Children.Count() once before you call Instantiate and once after and see how it changes. Otherwise the code is ok and if there are are 4 children it will iterate 4 times.

Comment: @Shintaro 
No code after instantiate runs, I tried debug logging the snapshot.ChildrenCount again after calling instantiate and nothing comes up in the console.

Comment: 1) Please update the code in your question to show the debug logs you tried, and their output.  --- 2) Also show the data at `"/Player/$scenarioName` in your database (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen
The debug.log messages are shown in the method, and I attached an image to the original question that shows the output.
I also included the text of the database now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the Unity API can only be executed in the Unity main thread!

You are using [`ContinueWith(Action<Task>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith#system-threading-tasks-task-continuewith(system-action((system-threading-tasks-task)))) without a specific `TaskScheduler`

> Creates a continuation that executes **asynchronously** when the target `Task` completes.

which doesn't assure that the callback is called on the main thread so latest at `Instantiate` it fails.

Firebase specific for Unity provides the task extension method [`ContinueWithOnMainThread`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/extensions/task-extension)

> Extension methods for `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` and `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T>` that allow the continuation function to be executed on the main thread in Unity.

you should rather use here

```
reference.Child("Player").Child(scenarioName).GetValueAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
{
    ....
});
```

In general make sure you haven't disabled any log type in the console. You should afaik have seen a warning telling you that `Instantiate` can not be used outside the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely method `Instantiate(treePrefab, loadTreePosition, loadTreeRotation);` throw an exception and that prevents further cycle iterations. Try to wrap up `Instantiate();` into try .. except and log catched exceptions